# Java generics: Set vs. Set<Object>

Tags: java, generics, casting

In Java, what's the difference between declaring a variable a `Set` versus a `Set<Object>`?  Shouldn't the two be equivalent?  Why is there a compile-time error when one assigns a `Set<Object>` variable to a `Set`?

Comment: You should maybe fix your question

Answer (score 3):

That isn't a compile-time error. It's just a warning. I.e this compiles fine:

```
Set s = new HashSet();
Set<Object> so = new HashSet<Object>();
s = so;
```

And incidentally, so does

```
so = s;
```

And they are basically the same from a usage perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Here is where the are not equivalent...

```
Set<String> s_str = new HashSet<String>();
Set s_plain = s_str;  // This is valid, although you will get a compiler warning

// This is invalid, the Set<String> cannot be implicitly cast to object even though
// it's *contents* are all objects.
Set<Object> s_obj = s_str;
```

Now let's say you wanted to have to take a generic Set for example as an argument to a function.  You can use extends

```
function void foo(Set<? extends Object> s) {}
```

In this case, a `Set`, a `Set<Object>` and a `Set<String>` could all be passed in to the function, even though they are all different.

Answer (score 1):

No: `Set<>` is generic, and `Set` isn't.  Logically, `Set<Object>` might be equivalent to `Set` (implicitly, `Set of Object`), but the bytecode is quite different :)

Suggestion:

Run `javap` command on your sample program and verify this for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Its the difference between Java 1.4 and below and 1.5 and above.

There's plenty of information out there on why.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

The two are not equivalent. When you assign a `Set<Object>` you increase the compilers' ability to detect unsafe manipulation of the set that would otherwise fail at runtime.

This is covered in Josh Bloch's excellent [Effective Java, Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), from which this example is unashamedly inspired:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> typesafeStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    unsafeAdd(typesafeStrings, new Integer(0)); // can add a Integer to a List<String>!
    String s = typesafeStrings.get(0); // fails at runtime, not safe

    typesafeStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    safeAdd(typesafeStrings, new Integer(0)); // compiler error, safe!
    s = typesafeStrings.get(0);

}

static void unsafeAdd(List list, Object o) {
    list.add(o);
}

static void safeAdd(List<Object> list, Object o) {
    list.add(o);
}
```